# Does region.contains() include the boundaries?

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if I created a square region using four paths and if I want to check if the user has clicked that region with Region.contains(). What happens if a user clicks on one of the paths(the boundaries)?

I ask this because I'm creating many regions next to each other using paths and when they click a certain region a specific sound to that region should trigger but what if they touch an intersection?

Comment: Why haven't you just tried it?

Comment: Not in a computer with it but yeah I could've read the documentation but i wasnt sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just follow WarrenFaith's comment.

But anyways,  the Region created will contain the boundary points.  As the reference reads if the region contains the point.  The boundary is part of the point.  Also you can see how the other methods and constructors work to make sure that this is true.

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Region.java